# passing data from itemView of Adapter between two Fragments

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout

Below code of adapter of RecyclerView

```
 public interface SelectMarket {
    void selectMarket(DataMarket dataMarket);
}
public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView marketTitleName;
    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        marketTitleName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_title_custom);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectMarket.selectMarket(marketName.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "id "+getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the code I shows you the `ViewHolder`
where I set `onClickListener`
I want to click on that and then go to other Fragment called SelectRoomFragment

and in Method of `SelectMarket()` I wrote inside the codes which will help me to go the the Next Fragment like this :

```
@Override
public void selectMarket(DataMarket dataMarket) {

    SelectRoomFragment selectRoomFragment= new SelectRoomFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("market",dataMarket.getTitle());
    selectRoomFragment.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,
            selectRoomFragment).commit();

}
```

**The Output Is**

[image]

Which is not looking Good like I want.

Comment: I cannot see the issue at a first glance, but I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-multiple-firebase-products-in-kotlin-16aade81ffec)/[repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the code below to onBindViewHolder

```
marketTitleName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_title_custom);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectMarket.selectMarket(marketName.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "id "+getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```